# Calling hive hql via shell script in oozie

Tags: shell, hive

I'm trying to call a hive script using a shell script via oozie. but its failing. Is it related to configuration or the way  I am calling the file?
I have 5 data nodes in my environment.

Note: I understood that its easier to call the hive script via a hive action. But I need the shell script to work so that I build a bigger shell script in which I can do various variable manipulation.

### shell script details:

```
File name : dly_date_tst.sh
Path      : /scripts/Linux/dly_date_tst.sh ( in HDFS )

File content :
--------------
#!/bin/bash
hive -f /scripts/Linux/tst_tab.hql
```

### Hive Script details:

```
Hive script name : tst_tab.hql
Path             : /scripts/Linux/tst_tab.hql

File content :
--------------

CREATE TABLE default.san_tst
(
alt_rated_amount double
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ",";
```

### Error details extracted from YARN

```
>>> Invoking Shell command line now >>

Exit code of the Shell command 3
<<< Invocation of Shell command completed <<<


<<< Invocation of Main class completed <<<

Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.ShellMain], exit code [1]

Oozie Launcher failed, finishing Hadoop job gracefully

Oozie Launcher, uploading action data to HDFS sequence file: hdfs://nameservice1/user/sandeepj/oozie-oozi/0000448-171022104125648-oozie-oozi-W/shell-350f--shell/action-data.seq
Successfully reset security manager from org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherSecurityManager@18e7143f to null

Oozie Launcher ends
```

Comment: Can you also post your oozie workflow?

Comment: The issue is now solved. although my script is stored in HDFS, I was calling it wrong from the shell script. wrong syntax : hive -f /scripts/Hive/test.hql  . The syntax that worked for me is :  hive  -f <(hdfs dfs -cat /scripts/Hive/test.hql) . Thank you all for spending your time on my query.